# Different layouts in Android RecyclerView issue

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm making a messenger functionality inside app and want to change layout gravity according to some passed value from holder (must be START or END). Everything works fine except gravity. It is set up at START for all holder. Is there any solution?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Message message = mMessageList.get(position);
    if(message.getSender().equals("System")){
        holder.content.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.message_bubble_out);
        holder.content.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        holder.messageLayout.setGravity(Gravity.END);
    }
    holder.content.setText(message.getContent());
}
```

Message Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_content"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/message_bubble_out"
            android:text="Hi, rangertS!"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

messageLayout definition:

```
messageLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.message_wrapper);
```

Comment: What is the type of your `messageLayout`?

Comment: messageLayout is a LinearLayout

Comment: Can you update your question to also include your holder and `messageLayout` definition? Because judging from the snippet you gave above, the problem seems to lie somewhere else.

Comment: Sure, I will include it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now that you given us a much elaborated explanation for your issue, I think I know the answer.

It seems like gravity is not to blame here.. As I said, your binding logic is on point.

The real culprit here is the way you laid out your message layout. Let's take a look at the lines I point out below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" <--- Use match_parent instead
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_content"
            android:layout_width="250dp" <--- Use wrap_content instead
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/message_bubble_out"
            android:text="Hi, rangertS!"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can see the two root causes of your problem in the annotated snippet I gave above. Let's elaborate a little more on this:

1. You're declaring your `LinearLayout` width to `wrap_content` meaning gravity will never play a role here. Why? Well because the layout will always be exactly the same size as its content! Try to make your `LinearLayout` be as width as its parent and you'll see gravity's effect.
2. 250dp for your `TextView` is, at least from my POV, a tad too big. There's a little reason to make a `TextView` bigger than the actual text it contains. Try to use wrap_content here instead.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! You made it :) I spend several hours trying to find a bug in a JAVA, while a solution was in a layout... It helped indeed :) Hooraaay!

Comment: I would be very happy to upvote your answer, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation.